# How to connect to Oracle from Java via OCI

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee

I need to connect java with oracle using  "jdbc:oracle:oci" connectivity. I have instant client in my system but i don't know how to connect java and oracle using OCI driver.

If anyone know, Please let me the step to make the connection.

Comment: Are you using standalone Java or your application runs on web server/application server (which one)? Is it Java SE or Java EE application? Do you use any ORM tool such as Hibernate or OpenJPA? An answer heavily relies on the type of environment you are planning to use.

Comment: I am using j2ee application. Now, I am able to conncet it now. what was my mistake is, I have not removed odjdbc14.jar from my environment. thanks for your response.